# How do you pass two parameters through url in django

Tags: django, django-models, django-views, django-forms, django-templates

I want to pass two parameters through url in django. First of all, here is my current html:

```
{% for lesson in lessons %}
{% for class in lessons %}
    <a href="{% url 'next-page' lesson.pk %}">Link to next page {{lesson}} {{class}}</a>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

And this is my url:

```
path('nextpage/<int:pk>/', ListView.as_view(), name='next-page'),
```

However, I want something like below:

```
{% for lesson in lessons %}
{% for class in lessons %}
    <a href="{% url 'next-page' lesson.pk class.pk %}">Link to next page {{lesson}} {{class}}</a>
{% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

and my url is:

```
path('nextpage/<int1:pk>/<int2:pk>', ListView.as_view(), name='next-page'),
```

Then I want to be able to access the primary keys in my view below:

```
class LessonList(generic.ListView):
    model = Lesson
    template_name = 'lesson_list.html'
    context_object_name = "lessons"

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

        lesson_id = self.kwargs['pk1']
        class_id = self.kwargs['pk2']

        return context
```

Obviously, the above code does not work. However, I want to basically be able to pass two parameters in the url, and access both of them in my view's `get_context_data`. Thank you, and please leave any questions you might have.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You made a mistake when defining your path, it should be `<int:pk1>` instead of <s>`<int1:pk>`</s>, so:

```
path('nextpage/<int:pk1>/<int:pk2>/', ListView.as_view(), name='next-page'),
```

then you can indeed work with:

```
<a href="{% url 'next-page' lesson.pk class.pk %}">Link to next page {{lesson}} {{class}}</a>
```

given of course both `lesson` and `class` exist in the context.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! However, is it okay to add multiple parameters in this way?

Comment: @codebuilder: yes, the [documentation of the `url` template tag](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#url) shows this as first example: `{% url 'some-url-name' v1 v2 %}` with `v1` and` v2` the two parameters.